# How can I skip reboot check and remove command line appearing during install of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

While i am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 using the configuration file method I sometimes get an error in installation due to system reboot checking.

After restarting my PC, SQL Server installs properly.  I want SQL Server setup to not check if the PC is rebooted or not. In SQL Server 2005 I can do this by using /norebootchk. How can I do this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Also while installing in silent mode by using `quiet=true` I am getting a SQL Server command prompt while installing.

[image]

How can I avoid this command prompt appearing when I am installing in quiet mode?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/78831/rule-restart-computer-failed-when-installing-sql-server-2008 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176857/installation-problem-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To skip the reboot check:

```
SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck
```

To hide the console window:

```
HIDECONSOLE=True
```

Full command line/.ini file options can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  The SkipRules option is not documented there and appears to be part of the general installer options.

Comment: Could you please provide a source for the `SkipRules` option? I don't see it on that page.

Comment: i also didnt get information about skiprules in that page.Also hideconsole=true didnt work for me.i included it in config file

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell that's undocumented, part of the general installer options.  I found references to it in various blog posts.  You can find one such reference in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3821329/333858).  I did included it and test it in an .ini and the log verified that the rule check was skipped.

Comment: WOW.the undocumented "SkipRules" works perfectly.But the documented HIDECONSOLE=True didnt work. i will try once  with /HIDECONSOLE in command line.

Comment: i used  /HIDECONSOLE  in command line and it worked fine